# Composer pull dependency from another branch on the same repo

Tags: php, git, symfony, composer-php, dependency-management

I have the following Composer 1.6.5 setup:

```
"require": {
    "CRMPicco/GolfBundle": "dev-golf-bundle"
},
"repositories": [
   {
       "type": "git",
       "url": "git@git.crmpicco.com:frontend/app.git"
   }
],
```

On the origin of git.crmpicco.com:frontend/app.git there exists the main branch of `master` and also a `golf-bundle` branch. I want to have the contents of the `golf-bundle` branch as a composer dependency in the `/vendor` directory. When I run a `composer update CRMPicco/GolfBundle` I get the following error:

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of
>   packages.
>
> Problem 1
>       - The requested package crmpicco/golfbundle dev-golf-bundle exists as CRMPicco/GolfBundle[dev-master] but these are rejected by your
>   constraint.

I have also flushed the cache and run dump-autoload:

```
composer clear-cache
composer dump-autoload --optimize
```

How can I configure composer to pull from the "golf-bundle" branch?

My `composer.json` from the `golf-bundle` branch:

```
{
  "name": "CRMPicco/GolfBundle",
  "type": "library",
  "require": {
    "php": ">=7.0",
    "symfony/config": "~2.8.34",
    "symfony/dependency-injection": "~2.8.34",
    "symfony/http-kernel": "~2.8.34",
    "chargebee/chargebee-php": "^2.0"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "CRMPicco\\GolfBundle\\": ""
    }
  },
  "extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "symfony-assets-install": "relative"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your `composer.json` from `git@git.crmpicco.com:frontend/app.git` on `golf-bundle` branch?

Comment: @rob006 Hi, sure - I have updated the question with the `composer.json` from the `golf-bundle` branch.

Comment: Does content of `composer.json` differ between `golf-bundle` and `master` branch?

Comment: @rob006 In terms of the name of the bundle, no it's the same. However I believe I found _why_ the problem was occuring. In my `composer.lock` the `CRMPicco/GolfBundle` was still referring to the old `package` in another location, which had a requirement on `dev-master`. I was having difficulties regenerating the `composer.lock` without trashing everything. Do you know how I could go about that?

Comment: Did you figure this one out properly? Even deleting lock file, it still says there's only 2 tags and doesnt see the third so it wont pull it.