# can't install latest git version of branch via composer

Tags: php, composer-php, phpseclib

My composer.json looks like this:

```
{
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

I'm trying to run `composer require phpseclib/phpseclib:dev-3.0` (based off of https://stackoverflow.com/a/33526908/569976) but when I try I get this error:

```
  [InvalidArgumentException]
  Could not find a matching version of package phpseclib/phpseclib. Check the package spelling, your version cons
  traint and that the package is available in a stability which matches your minimum-stability (dev).
```

3.0 is a valid branch name (https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/tree/3.0) so I'm not entirely sure what the problem is.

I also tried using this as my composer.json:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib.git"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

No luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dev-branch` convention is used for branches that does not look like version. `3.0` branch looks like version, so you need to use `branch.x-dev` convention - `3.0.x-dev` in your case. This is explained in [documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#branches). You can also find list of available versions for this package on [Packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/phpseclib/phpseclib).