# UnexpectedValueException Could not parse version constraint mybranch: Invalid version string "mybranch"

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm trying to develop a PHP library (called `foo/bar`) using Composer in dir `/work/a` with the `composer.json` contents:

```
{
    "name": "foo/bar",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.2"
    }
}
```

`/work/a` is a git project and I'm on the branch `mybranch`

I'm trying to use this lib in another project locally (called `testing/foobar`) using Composer in dir `work/b` with the `composer.json` contents:

```
{
    "name": "testing/foobar",
    "type": "project",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "/work/a"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.4",
        "foo/bar": "mybranch"
    }
}
```

When running `$ composer install` in `/work/b` I get the error:

```
[UnexpectedValueException]                                            
  Could not parse version constraint mybranch: Invalid version string "mybranch"
```

Comment: I think that the error message shown does not match the composer.json that you provide...

Comment: You're right. I updated for a simple example, but forgot to update the error message. Updated now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to prefix your branch name with `dev-`, so your branch name will have to be `dev-mybranch`.

> [Loading a package from a VCS repository](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#loading-a-package-from-a-vcs-repository)
>
> ...
> In `composer.json`, you should prefix your custom branch name with `"dev-"`.
> ...

Also check this Q/A ["Composer require branch name"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33525885/composer-require-branch-name).

#### Change branch name to have `dev-` prefix, add it to `/work/b` project:

```json
{
    "name": "testing/foobar",
    "type": "project",
    "repositories": [
        {
          "type": "vcs",
          "url": "/work/a"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.4",
        "foo/bar": "dev-mybranch"
    }
}
```

#### Run `composer install`:

```
❯ composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing foo/bar (dev-mybranch 85c97b7): Cloning 85c97b7b23 from cache
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
```

Comment: Doh! I completely missed the part that the branch name HAS to specifically be `dev-<something>`. I'm coming from rubygems/maven/npm where testing libs locally is similar, but different.