# composer require nested branch?

Tags: git, gitlab, composer-php

I'm making a custom composer package on GitLab, for the first commits I referenced the `master` branch in the `composer.json` of my project as

```
"require": {
    ...    
    "owner/project": "master"
    ...
}
```

and it was all good, it actually downloaded my package in the `vendor` folder.

Now I want to start making branches for each releases, so I named my first release branch as `releases/1.x` and tried to reference it as

```
"require": {
    ...
    "owner/project": "releases/1.x"
    ...
}
```

but this gave me the error

```
[UnexpectedValueException]
Could not parse version constraint releases/1.x: Invalid version string "releases/1.x"
```

so I tried to inline alias it as

```
"require": {
    ...
    "owner/project": "dev-releases/1.x as 1.x-dev"
    ...
}
```

but now I got

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
  - The requested package owner/project dev-releases/1.x as 1.x-dev exists as owner/project[dev-master] but these are rejected by your constraint.
```

So, how can I reference my branch in `composer.json`?

[Composer require branch name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33525885/composer-require-branch-name): This question was pointed out to me, but as already said i had no problem when working with master branch

### Update #1

Now i've created 2 releases on gitlab, tagging a commit from `master` branch as `v.1.0.0` and another one from `releases/1.x` as `1.0`, but none fo the below attempts succed

```
"require": {
    ...
    "owner/project": "v.1.0.0",
    "owner/project": "1.0.0",
    "owner/project": "1.1",
    ...
}
```

Each one gives me the same old error.

### Update #2

Found [this question on github](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/8769) and noticed that my `composer.json` has no `version` entry, so I deleted all current releases, added

```
"version": "1.0.1",
```

to my package project `composer.json` and created a new release with both tag name and release title `v1.0.1`.
Then updated my other project `composer.json` to match new release
with `owner/project: "1.0.1"` but nothing changed:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package owner/project 1.0.1 exists as owner/project[dev-master] but these are rejected by your constraint.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Composer require branch name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33525885/composer-require-branch-name)

Comment: @NicoHaase unfortunately no, when requiring master branch it worked correctly

Comment: Have you tried using `dev-releases/1.x` without any other stuff?

Comment: actually no, searching online leads me directly to inline aliasing, i'll try it as soon as possible

Comment: @NicoHaase i've tried your solution, but it didn't worked; same error as before